# Pearsonr and p-value

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, p-value, pearson-correlation

I am analyzing some data in pandas and plotting correlations between two variables using `sns.jointplot()` function. The results for correlation between these two function looks like this:
[image]

The value for pearsonr is 0.41 and p is 5e-18. What can i infer from these two values. Is there a good relationship between these two variables are not.

Also if I want to just display pearsonr on the plot, how should I change my code. Below is the code that I a using currently.

```
ax=sns.jointplot(df['Comfort'], df['Assurance'],data=df, kind="kde", color='r');
```

Comment: What do you mean by _if I want to just display pearsonr on the plot, how should I change my code_?

Comment: By default pearsonr and p value are displayed, as you can see in the image. I don't want p-value to be displayed on the plot.

Comment: What is your `seaborn`'s version?

Comment: @sentence its 0.8.1

Comment: your question about seaborn version made me chance seaborn version from  0.8.1 to 0.9.0 . Doing so make me get rid of pearsonr and p-value from the plot. Thanks @sentence for pointing in the right direction. 
But coming back to my first part of my initial question that what does pearsonr and p value of 0.41 and 5e-18 respectively infer about the correlation of my two variables.

Comment: Indeed, it was what I suspected since new version of seaborn does NOT display that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The value for pearsonr is 0.41 and p is 5e-18. What can i infer from
>   these two values. Is there a good relationship between these two
>   variables are not.

Roughly speaking:

- The size of a correlation coefficient (`0.41`) suggests a low positive correlation.
- p-value (`5e-18`) suggests that the correlation coefficient is statistically significant, being much less than 0.01 (0.01 ---> the risk of concluding that a correlation exists when, actually, no correlation exists is 1%).
- please, remember that Pearson correlation coefficient only measures linear relationships. You can get Pearson correlation coefficient `0` for variables (datasets) with a strong nonlinear relationship. Moreover, you are assuming that your variables (datasets) are normally distributed.

> Also if I want to just display pearsonr on the plot, how should I
>   change my code.

`seaborn 0.9.0` does not display that information. To add that information, you can compute the value using [`scipy.stats.pearsonr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html), then showing it as part of the title of your figure.